# android - google maps v2 - keep updating location from service

Tags: android, google-maps, android-service, android-location, android-googleapiclient

I have followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-google-maps-for-android-basics--cms-24635) and now I have a working activity with google map fragment.

I need to keep track on the location of my app's users - the fragment has a `onLocationChanged` method which fires when location is changed, and on that method I update **My Database** with the user's location, draw the user on the map and more stuff.

The only issue is - I want to also have a **service** that will always send updates to my database and update each user's location, also when the **app is closed**.

Should I put the `onLocationChanged` method in both the fragment and service somehow? because when the **app is on the foreground**, I also do more things on the `onLocationChanged` beside updating the database, like drawing the map etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have your service receive all location updates, and use `LocalBroadcastManager` to broadcast intents with the location updates to any fragment or activity that registers an internal `BroadcastReceiver` with the intent filter?  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/) on how to use `LocalBroadcastManager`.  Also, here is an example of how I made my internal `BroadcastReceivers`:

```
static class InternalBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    MyFragment mMyFragment;

    public InternalBroadCastReceiver(MyFragment fragment){
        mMyFragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final MyFragment fragment = mMyFragment;

        if (fragment != null) {
            Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra("myLocation");

            //...  Do something with your location here, for example:
            fragment.updatemap(location);
        }
    }
}
```